# Python/SWIG: Return Array by Index

Tags: python, c++, return-value, swig

I am trying to output an array of values from a C++ function wrapped using SWIG for Python. I know how to do this for the simple case of returning a C++ array using the following typemap:

```
%apply (double* ARGOUT_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(double* output_array, int length)};
```

with the associated C++ code looking like:

```
void MyClass::retrieveArray(double* output_array, int length) {
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
        output_array[i] = _array[i];
}
```

The usage from Python looks like:

```
output_array = my_class_instance.returnArray(length)
```

However, I want to take this a step further and return an array using an index into a multi-dimensional array. So the C++ code would look like:

```
void MyClass::retrieveArray(double* output_array, int length, int index) {
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
        output_array[i] = _multi_dimensional_array[index][i];
}
```

However, the typemap would need to be changed to accommodate the index. I have tried:

```
%apply (double* ARGOUT_ARRAY1, int DIM1, int index) {(double* output_array, 
        int length, int index)};
```

but that does not seem to work. I also know that the size of the returned array in this case will be 6 doubles, but I am not sure how to relay that information to SWIG.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to apply the same typemap as before:

```
%apply (double* ARGOUT_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(double* output_array, int length)};
```

This will match the parameters `double* output_array` and `int length` of `MyClass::retrieveArray`. To call the function from python, use:

```
output_array = my_class_instance.retrieveArray(length, index)
```

or, since you already know that the length will be 6:

```
output_array = my_class_instance.retrieveArray(6, index)
```

You can also modify your C++ code to use the following function signature if you already know the size of the array at compile time:

```
void MyClass::retrieveArray(double output_array[6], int index) {...}
```

and then use a different typemap:

```
%apply (double ARGOUT_ARRAY1[6]) {(double output_array[6])};
```

See also the [documentation for numpy.i](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/swig.interface-file.html), which I assume you are using.